# AWS Lambda issue with psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I'm trying to import psycopg2 into my python 3.6 lambda function but I keep running into the error message `'Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size'`

I'm uploading the zip file directly into the lambda function through the AWS console. I've tried using https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 library but it's given me the same message.

I've been able to successfully run my script on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)), and I've even tried uploading the EC2 instance psycopg2 library onto lambda, but I still keep getting the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Python are you using to build the zip?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well when trying to upload the .zip containing my Lambda. The issue for me was that I was compressing my Lambda from one directory above.

The solution was running the zip command within the directory containing the Lambda function itself as opposed to running zip from its parent directory.

For example, if your lambda function exists within the directory ~/lambda as lambda_function.py along with any additional libraries (i.e. multiprocessing) - you should zip your Lambda Deployment Package by doing the following.

```
$ cd ~/lambda
$ zip lambda_function.zip lambda_function.py
$ zip -r lambda_function.zip multiprocessing*
```

Uploading the resulting .zip file should resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes, I should of posted the solution on here but I was doing the exact same thing and came to the same conclusion. Zipping the lambda function one directory up, then later on moving them down in the Lambda UI is apparently a big no for AWS.

Comment: Why is does compressing the function this way make a difference?

Comment: The folder structure of the .zip file matters even if you later move around files on the inline editor. I can confirm it, I was running into the same problem, with AWS lambda complaining about phentsize of my .so files. I couldn't believe it, but indeed the file structre of the zip file does matter, so reorder it locally, recompress and upload again. When you nail the file structure, then the modules do work!